# Error running Webpack5 with Babel: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'

Tags: webpack, babel-loader, webpack-5

Trying to get Babel and Webpack 5 playing nicely together, but I receive the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
```

Most links I see refer to an old version of Node (v12 is most often mentioned) but running `node -v` I can see the following version is installed:

```
v18.12.1
```

Package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Trying out webpack 5 and babel.",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "install"
    ]
  }
}
```

Webpack config looks like this:

```
const entry = {
    example: './_build/js/example.js'
};
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: entry,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        static: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    },
};
```

Full stack trace of the error is:

```
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\path\to\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:24:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
```

The actual typescript file contents are arbitrary -

```
export default class FooBar {
    Load(): void {
        let foo = 'bar';
        let stack = 'overflow';
    }
}
```

I get the same error if it is empty.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and installing babel-loader version 8.0.4 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem.

**Solution**

The problem is with the node.js older version.

- Delete your package-lock.json
- Delete node_modules folder

Uninstall your node.js older version and Update to the latest node.js version by installing from the official site https://nodejs.org/en/download will solve the problem.

Also check npm version, and update to latest npm version by using:
`npm install -g npm`

At the end also update all npm packages by: `npm --force update` This will update all packages in the package.json and installs latest packages.